# last -t [date] not filtering results by date

Tags: command-line

If I run:

```
last -t 20150101010101
```

I still get logins displayed (even though the date is in the future)

If I run

```
last -t 20140723123000
```

I still get logins displayed from months back.

I would expect to only see logins from earlier on today. Is this correct?

Comment: from man last: `-t, --until time --> Display the state of logins until the specified time.`, so the output you are getting makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`last -t YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` shows the status of the login files up to the date specified, rather than since the date specified.